# Where do I assign SDL 2.0.3 directories in NetBeans 8.0?

Tags: c++, netbeans, configuration, sdl-2, netbeans-8

I don't know where to put the libraries nor which libraries are 64 bit or 32 bit. And it is becoming a pain spending most of my weekends trying to get a dynamic library to work. I'm using Windows 64 bit system but my program is 32 bit. Also I'm using C++. Can someone create a step by step guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you develop a 32 bit program, you should use a 32 Bit SDL library.

You can place your libraries (and their headers) *everywhere* - but if you are using MinGW better keep blanks out of the path. Just tell the compiler where he can *find* those files.

And here's how to do this in NB:

First, go to **`Right click Project --> Properties`**

- **`C++ Compiler`**: at **`Include Directories`** set the path where the **headers** of your libs are
- **`Linker`**:

  - at **`Additional Library Directories`** add the path where your lib **binaries** are
  - at **`Libraries`** add the **name** (!) of your library - without prefix *lib* or *file extension*

If your Libraries are named eg. `libSDL2.dll` set `SDL2` as name; if `SDL2.dll` only `SDL2`.